# How to receive POST form data in node.js from client

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

Hello guys i am a newbie when it comes with web development, especially working with node.js, i want to find out how i can receive data sent from client via ajax Post.

below is the script i wrote to post the form data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ecoachSignIn(){ 
var user = $('#user').val();
var password = $('#pass').val();

var SignIn ={
    user : $('#user').val();
    pass : $('#pass').val();
};
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'https://api.ecoachsolutions.com/main.php?ecoachsignin=1&server=remote&user='+username+'&pass='+password,
    data: {
            user : $('#user').val();
            pass : $('#pass').val();
          },
    success: function(creditials){

    }
});
alert("Hello! your username is "+username+" and password is "+password);
}
```

this is the form itself

```
<form style="margin-top:25%; margin-left:30%" method="post" action='/'>                                
  <input class="input" type="text" id="user" required="true" name="username" placeholder="Username">               

  <input class="button-1" style="background:#000" onClick="ecoachSignIn()" type="submit" value="Log in">

 <div style="margin-top:10px">  
  <input class="input" type="password" id="pass" name="password" required="true" placeholder="Password">
</div> 
</form>
```

node.js server code

```
    router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var request = require("request"),
      user_name=req.body.username,//this picks the username frome the form directly not from the javascript i created to post the data
      password=req.body.password,//same problem with the username
      url = req.query.url;//trying to get the url in my jQuery at client side but not working
  console.log("Username = "+user_name+", password is "+password);
  request.get(
    {
        url : url
    },
    function (error, response, body) {

        // Do more stuff with 'body' here
       if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var json_body = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(json_body); 
        status = json_body.status;
        success = json_body.msg;
        fname = json_body.profile.fname;
    console.log("hi "+fname); // Print the username.
    console.log("status is "+status); // Print the status.
    console.log("success is "+success); // Print the success.
  }
    }
);
  res.end("yes");
});
```

My major problem is how to process this in node.js backend server
Hope my question is clear ....thanks

Comment: Your URL is `.../main.php`. Are you sure you are using node.js and not a PHP web server? Why do you pass the parameters both as form parameters (`data : { ... }`) and as query parameters (`...&user='+username+'&...`)? One way is sufficient. The `data`way is the better one.

Comment: How is your node server handling the incoming data? Where is the variables `username`and `password`? Why are you passing the data at the URL and in the `data` object of $.post? And if it is node, why the POST is in an PHP page?

Comment: You appear to be asking for a complete guide to writing a web server in Node.js. That's far too broad a question for stackoverflow. Try reading the documentation and narrowing down your problem.

Comment: @Quentin my apologies, sorry fo the misunderstanding and confusion i created here....i just edited my post with the node.js code to receive the data from the clients side

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `return false` from your `ecoachSignIn` function to prevent the normal HTML form submission (and so that your ajax request can take place)?

Answer (score -1):

Your server side code:

```
 user_name=req.body.username,//this picks the username frome the form directly not from the javascript i created to post the data
 password=req.body.password,//same problem with the username
```

Your client side code:

```
 user : $('#user').val();
 pass : $('#pass').val();
```

You call the fields `user` and `pass` on the client but `username` and `password` on the server. You have to use the same name in both places.

It works when you use the form normally because the name attributes match the names you use the on server.

Comment: Community wiki because the answer boils down to "You made a typo".

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but when i corrected it  returned Username and password as undefined

Comment: How are you parsing the body? What does it look like if you console.log it? Have you checked that the data is sent correctly in the request by examining the browser's Net tab?